# Обновить данные при изменение select. Angular

Tags: angular

Size является enum.

```
...
  sizes: Size[];
  selectedCost: number;
...
...
```

Есть такой select:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let size of sizes">{{sizeConvertToString(size)}}</option>
</select>
<div>Цена: {{selectedCost}}</div>
```

Как из него можно получить сам элемент который выбран. И при изменении происходило изменение цены.

Comment: Что говорит документация на ваш запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `ngModel` на тег `select`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSize">
    <option *ngFor="let size of sizes">{{sizeConvertToString(size)}}</option>
</select>
<div>Цена: {{selectedCost}}</div>
```

В коде компонента используем getter, который автоматически обновит цену выбранного элемента

```
...
  selectedSize: Size;
  sizes: Size[];
  get selectedCost(): number {
     return this.selectedSize.cost;
  }
...
...
```